# How to keep menu dropdown shown, navigate through menu items and dropdown items and close on 'close' button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did the search but was no able to find the solution.
I need a dropdown menu to be open always, even through navigation to other menu items and dropdown menu items. And be able to close only on .close button.
on mouseenter piece:

```
$('.main-nav ul > li').mouseenter(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active').find('.dropdown-menu').show();
 }).mouseleave(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('active').find('.dropdown-menu').hide();

});
```

on button click piece:

```
$('.dropdown-menu .close').click( function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-toggle').parent().removeClass('active');
    console.log('close btn!');
});
```

I can check also, if clicked outside of the menu:

```
var container = $('.dropdown');

//check if the clicked area is dropdown or not
if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    console.log('clicked out!');
}
```

But how to keep the dropdown always shown aka Bootstrap?
and only close on button '.close' or re-load?
I can implement it on click, it works as I need, but the request is to do it on hover. Show dropdown items on hover like MegaNav, able to change on hover over all menu items and close ONLY on button, not on mouseleave. Same time able to navigate through top menu items and all subs dropdown items.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lgvuom/

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are having trouble doing. Could you illustrate your problem using the code snippet tool so that we know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @KentAnderson, sorry for the confusion, I'll update the code. In meanwhile, the problem I'm dealing with is I need a dropdown menu to be open on hover and keep open always, no matter what the user is doing/navigationg. And close only on button click, not on mouseleave. If you have the idea, please help me. Actually, you don't need to even look at my code, I have pieces of it ;-)

Comment: @KentAnderson, I've added a fiddle file https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lgvuom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to jQuery forum and JΛ̊KE :-)
Here is the solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.main-nav ul > li').mouseenter(function(e){
  $('.active').removeClass('active').find('.dropdown-menu').hide();
        $(this).addClass('active').find('.dropdown-menu').show();
     }); 
 $('.dropdown-menu .close').click( function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').hide().parent().removeClass('active');
        console.log('close btn!');
    });
    
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.dropdown.active > a {
  color: green;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    top: 33px;
    min-width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    background: #f7f7f7;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper .close {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 0;
    top: 5px;
    outline: none;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper .close:before, .dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper .close:after {
    content: "";
    opacity: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper .close:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-wrapper .close:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.category-menu a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="toggle">Category 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
          <!--- close button  --->
          <button class="close"></button>
          <div class="category-menu">
            <a href="#">Subcategory 1</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 2</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="toggle">Category 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
          <!--- close button  --->
          <button class="close"></button>
          <div class="category-menu">
            <a href="#">Subcategory 1</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 2</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="toggle">Category 3</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
          <!--- close button  --->
          <button class="close"></button>
          <div class="category-menu">
            <a href="#">Subcategory 1</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 2</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="toggle">Category 4</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
          <!--- close button  --->
          <button class="close"></button>
          <div class="category-menu">
            <a href="#">Subcategory 1</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 2</a>
            <a href="#">Subcategory 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lgvuom/2/) with a simple example of how it could work.

I updated the close button with a unique ID and some descriptive text. I then added the following code to run when the button is clicked in order to close the dropdown menu.

```
$("#btnCloseMenu").on("click", function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

I then commented out the line of code that closed the menu on "mouseleave" so that it wouldn't close when the user moves their cursor away. Depending on the complexity of the menu structure (ie: submenus), your solution may require some additional logic so that the user can browse.

There are many ways to do what you are asking. Go with whatever option makes the most sense to you.

Comment: I checked it, it's not working.. The one it was before was working. it's not a solution... Can you please make it work?

Comment: I think I reverted it back ;-).. so what are my options? if I knew them, I would not ask here... any help? I need 911 js help here...